# Checking Checkboxes in a PDF with iText7 in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext7

I have a sample pdf, that I am filling out programmatically as such (using iText7):-

```cs
string name = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
string pdfTemplate = @"..\WebApplication1\Sample.pdf";
string newFile = @"..\WebApplication1\completed_sample.pdf";

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfTemplate).SetUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(newFile));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
PdfFormField toSet;

// This doesn't work //
fields.TryGetValue("TypeofApplication.1", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("/On");

// This works //
fields.TryGetValue("FullName", out toSet);
toSet.SetValue(name);

form.FlattenFields();
pdf.Close();
```

I am able to fill out the text boxes in the pdf, but not to fill out the radio buttons/checkboxes.

Type of Application has two options in my `cshtml` page:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Application_Type", "New") New 
@Html.RadioButton("Application_Type", "Renew") Renewal
```

and when I look through my values dictionary, I see that there are 3 options:

1. TypeofApplication
2. TypeofApplication.1
3. TypeofApplication.2

How do I set the checkboxes as `checked = true`.

My logic is as follow:

```
if(dr.Application_Type == "New"){
    fields.TryGetValue("TypeofApplication.1", out toSet);
    toSet.SetValue("/On");}
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Always read tags before applying them.  [tag:itext] applies to iText versions prior to version 7.

Comment: I wanted to get maximum view on my question

Comment: Please share the / an example pdf.

Comment: i cannot share an example pdf

Comment: is there a way to look at the possible values for a field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way I figured this out:-

1) I opened the pdf, set the checkbox as checked and saved it in my workspace folder.
2) Then, I programmatically opened the file and inspected the field value as such:-

```
            string pdfTemplate = @"..\WebApplication1\Sample.pdf";

            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfTemplate).SetUnethicalReading(true), new PdfWriter(newFile));
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
            IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
            PdfFormField toSet;
            fields.TryGetValue("TypeofApplication", out toSet);
            var x = toSet.GetValueAsString();
```

Now, I know the value of x, which is the checked field. (New or Renew). I used this technique to find all values possible for any given checkbox, radiobutton list, et cetera.